# Higher (4+) dimension/axis in numpy...are they ever actually used in computation?

Tags: numpy, axis, dimension

what I mean by the title is that sometimes I come across code that requires numpy operations (for example sum or average) along a specified axis. For example:

```
np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)
```

I can grasp this concept, but do we actually ever do these operations also along higher dimensions? Or is that not a thing? And if yes, how do you gain intuition for high-dimensional datasets and how do you make sure you are working along the right dimension/axis?

Comment: Yes, they are very much used in many domains. For example, a video sequence can be represented by a 4D array, dimensions being time, height, width and color channels. If you now have a collection of video clips, all the same duration, then you can put that into a 5D array, the first one being the "clip id". And so on. There are many other example you might think of. You will get an intuition for it when you work in an actual problem that requires it, and have a good understanding of the nature and format of the data.

Comment: Let's say you have a weather simulation. Each point has latitude, longitude, and elevation.  There's your first 3 dims right there.  THEN each point has temperature, humidity, pressure, THREE components of windspeed, and probably more things I'm not thinking of.  There you have nine dimensions.

Comment: Sum on an axis of a stack of color images might actually be easier to visualize. (batch, height, width, color), e.g. (1000, 256, 256, 3).  The change in shape if you take a mean across images, or compress the color axis to a b/w intensity is obvious.